# Why std::dec does not convert hexadecimal memory address to decimal?

Tags: c++, hex, decimal

```
int x = 99;
printf("&x = %p\n", &x);
printf("&x = %d\n", &x);
std::cout << &x << std::endl;
std::cout << std::dec << &x << std::endl; // problematic line (5)
std::cout << std::dec << 0x0D << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
&x = 0x7ffe5f1d0434
&x = 1595737140 // I don't think this is correct.
0x7ffe5f1d0434
0x7ffe5f1d0434
13 // decimal of 0x0D
```

I don't understand why fifth line above does not output decimal representation of the address of variable `x`. My usage of `std::dec` should be correct, because it works for `0x0D`. So, I suspect `&x` might not be a hexadecimal number as I think it is. But, I am not sure, so wanted to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `0x0D` is an integer value. A pointer is not. Try `static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&x)`.

Comment: `0x7ffe5f1d0434` represents 6 bytes. If you discard the two most significant bytes and convert `0x5f1d0434` to decimal, you'll see it matches up with your output of `1595737140`. That suggests to me that the output is being truncated to a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @JohnH probably, it gave a warning though : `c.cpp:9:27: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int*’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("&x = %d\n", &x);`

Comment: Good warning. They both should be `static_cast` to `uintptr_t`.